# asp.net high cpu w3wp.exe

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, asp.net-mvc-4

I have one table and for doing any insert or update i am using the merge statement
so i have a MVC4 webapi hosted as a service which accepts AJAX calls.
on receiving the ajax call, i am using entity framework to call a stored procedure
in the stored proc, I am using Merge to decide if the row exists then update else insert
I am using merge on a single table.
everything is fine on dev
however on running a soak load test, after 5 hours we see a high cpu for w3wp on the web server.
and after around 7 hours, we see around 1.9 million rows in DB
we truncated the table and started the test again for 1 hour and CPU went normal to around 5 to 7%
So can it be that if the number of rows grows beyond a certain limit, the app can cause high CPU.
At this point, the only point we notice is that when the no of rows in DB grows, the CPU hikes.
This is just an analysis. We haven't proved it.
The table has primary key which is composed of 2 fields
one is sessionid(varchar32) where the asp.net sessionid is stored
and a name column(varchar(128)
this 2 field composes the primary key and is clustered index
every browser instance sends the asp.net  sessionid and a name for every request and based on that, a record gets inserted or updated.
I am thinking if a stored proc can cause high cpu in web server.
SQL exists on a different box
any suggestion would be helpful

Comment: Please clean the question, split it to few chapters if needed and format the code (or even code expressions).

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you must be enumerating all elements of a table in a linq query somewhere in the app. Junior developers do not know the difference between IQueryable and a List.